# Unable to open video link / html link in clue cumber report - trivago

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

I tried to embed sauce lab video link to the clue cumber report and i was successfully able to add the link but when i click on it nothing is happening.
two issues:
1. nothing happening when clicked on link in IE browser and if i inspect the element and open the link in another tab , i was able to see the video playing in windows media player
2.not able to find pie charts and links in Chrome browser , when i inspect the page , there i see many errors in the console .

```
        String videoLink = "<a href="ReusableMethodToGetVideoLink">Video<a>";
        scenario.embed(videoLink.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), "text/html");
```

Can someone please help me.

Comment: What happens if you use an end tag (  String videoLink = "<a href="ReusableMethodToGetVideoLink">Video</a>";  ) ?

Comment: In past few months, I tried same. Video gets embedded but when when we click on player icon inside html report, nothing happens, could be some security concerns, not sure. So ad workaround I have been adding video hyper link in report and when we click on link, video start getting download as general file. So I am using that. Let me know if you too think about this.

Comment: @MrCas : Same result !! nothing happening

Comment: @TheSociety : yeah thank you  , this way it works , but wanted to check why this happening.